# Exception occur when refresh page in Tomcat JSR 356 websocket

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, jsr356

I have ServerEndpoint class:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket", configurator = ServletAwareConfig.class)
public class WebsocketEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("OnOpen");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("OnClose");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("OnMessage");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("OnError");
    }
}
```

When I refresh page, onError invoked and exception t contains next description:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

What can be reason?

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same exception when I use Chrome or Chromium to open the page. (It never occurs when I use Firefox). I'm not sure if you are using Chrome too. I guess it is because of the V8 engine.

My solution is to close the web socket before leaving the page:

`window.addEventListener ("beforeunload", function(){ socket.close(); });`

But I have not seen any exceptions like this when I use [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/) as my web socket server. Hopes someone can show the direct reason of this problem. Thanks!